# SqlDateTimeOverFlow error

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmwzs.png)I want to insert employee information in a table.There is a field name called as DateHired. Eventhough we have inserted the correct date ,its showing us the error saying Error - SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.What should I do now and what should I check for?

Comment: What's your format when you insert to DB?

Comment: Which dbms? Column data type? Show us your INSERT statement.

Comment: DateHired is alone DateTime with a calender

Comment: Sounds like _SQL Server_, but where is your C# code, please?

Comment: we need to see your code and the format you are passing it over in in order to help you.

Comment: See the above picture for more information

Comment: See the link @SimonPrice

Comment: @raghav what is the format you are passing the date in

Comment: SqlDbType.DateTime  @SimonPrice

Comment: what format as in dd-MM-yyyy, or dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss etc..

Comment: YYYY-MM--DD is the format @SimonPrice

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue, and I'm going to make an assumption here that dates are getting pushed down as a string. If I'm wrong, the rest of this may not apply to you but it might help someone else :-)

Make sure you aren't getting US and rest-of-world formats mixed up. For example 12/31/9999 is invalid in UK locale as it should be 31/12/9999. The former will give an overflow/out-of-range error (as there aren't 31 months).

If you need to push dates through as a string, the safest way is to use ISO format, i.e.: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`, for example: 2015-12-17T08:30:00. That 'T' that separates date from time is important. Without it, local locale rules kick in again.

A second safe way, especially if we're talking US vs. UK is to name the month, i.e.', "17 Dec 2015". This won't work if we're looking at US/UK vs. French, but it's okay for anglocentric apps.

Finally, make sure your app is connecting to the SQL database using a login with the right language. Execute `DBCC USEROPTIONS` as the user your application connects as - this will tell you the language and dateformat that user is using. You can change this through SSMS (Security -> Logins -> [find user] -> Properties -> Default language).

Some people might recommend using `SET DATEFORMAT` to work around this - but this comes with a danger when used liberally, especially within stored procedures: `SET DATEFORMAT` forces an execution plan to be recompiled at each execution (as documented in Microsoft's whitepaper [Plan Caching in SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx) - scroll down to "Factors that affect plan re-use"), and thus has an adverse impact on performance